# why is this html code valid?

Tags: html, validation

can someone explain to me , why is this code valid?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html<head>
    <title//
    <p ltr<span id=p></span</p>
    </>
```

I look forward to receiving your reply. thanks for attention

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? (You have a *lot* of different HTML features which aren't commonly used packed into that, if you had a specific question about one of them then this would probably be a better question)

Comment: Doesn't seems valid for me.

Comment: It throws 7 warnings. For me, this is not valid. If you don't close tags, a warning will shown.

Comment: @ichan-akira — Well, as far as the DTD is concerned, it is valid.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude — Those warnings have nothing to do with validity.

Comment: Have tried it in https://validator.w3.org/check, and it show that **This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.01 Strict!** but with **Passed, 7 warning(s)**.

Comment: @ichan-akira — Right, so it passed, which means it is valid.

Comment: @Quentin there are warnings. In my job, the coding quality is a MUST.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude — So? The question is asking about validity. It isn't asking about quality. It isn't asking about best practise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those HTML code is valid because HTML 4.01 allow those things, and Internet browser who respect doctype, will display that with no problem.

If you change the doctype to HTML 5, it will definitely give error, since HTML 5 is more strict about writing proper HTML tag.

**HTML 4.01** (*no error* according to https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html<head>
    <title//
    <p ltr<span id=p></span</p>
    </>
```

**HTML 5** (*15 error* according to https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html<head>
    <title//
    <p ltr<span id=p></span</p>
    </>
```

---

**Explanation:**

That HTML structure is valid because according to HTML 4.0.1 Specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/):

> **B.3.7 Shorthand markup**
>
> Some SGML SHORTTAG constructs save typing but add no expressive capability to the SGML application. Although these constructs technically introduce no ambiguity, they reduce the robustness of documents, especially when the language is enhanced to include new elements. Thus, while SHORTTAG constructs of SGML related to attributes are widely used and implemented, those related to elements are not. Documents that use them are conforming SGML documents, but are unlikely to work with many existing HTML tools.
>
> The SHORTTAG constructs in question are the following:
>
> - NET tags:
>     `<name/.../`
> - closed Start Tag:
>     `<name1<name2>`
> - Empty Start Tag:
>     `<>`
> - Empty End Tag:
>     `</>`

Quoted from https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.7.

---

So based on that HTML 4.01 Specification, this means:

```
1     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
2        <html<head>
3        <title//
4        <p ltr<span id=p></span</p>
5        </>
```

- Line 1 is valid doctype for HTML 4.0.1.
- Line 2 is valid `<html>` open tag, closing `</html>` tag is not necessary.
- Line 2 is also valid `<head>` open tag, closing `</head>` tag is not necessary.
- Line 3 is a valid `<title>` open tag which Internet browser read `<title// <p ltr<span id=p>` simply as `<title>`, closing `</title>` tag is not necessary.
- Line 4-5 is the content (inner HTML) of `<title>` tag which is `</span</p> </>` (this is what Internet browser display as the title of the page).

That was my additional explanation. Hope that able to help you.

Comment: "Those HTML code is valid because HTML 4.01 allow those things" — You're basically saying that it is valid because it is valid, which isn't really very helpful.

Comment: "and Internet browser who respect doctype, will display that with no problem" — Not so. That code example uses a lot of features of HTML which most browsers have *never* supported.

Comment: @Quentin I've updated my explanation, hope that explain it.

Comment: @ichan-akira This answer is really good, thanks.

Comment: @Kermani I'm happy to be able to help.